# Bash alias autocompletion that considers only *.foo files

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Whenever I want to start editing my *LaTeX* sources by launching, e.g., the command `vim pdeOptAff.tex`, I find that bash the (tab)-autocompletion is still tedious because the folder typically contains a bunch of files with the same name but different endings:

```
$ ls

pdaeOptAff.aux  pdaeOptAff.out         pdaeOptAff.tex.latexmain
pdaeOptAff.bbl  pdaeOptAff.pdf         pdaeOptAff.toc
pdaeOptAff.blg  pdaeOptAff.synctex.gz
pdaeOptAff.log  pdaeOptAff.tex
```

Since I **always** want to open the the `~.tex` file, I would love to have a filter that makes autocomplete expand only the `~.tex` files.

In addition, I have an alias defined: `alias g='gvim --remote-silent'`. So this filter, in particular, should work for the alias.

Comment: `$ g *.tex<Tab>` should expand the only `*.tex` file in the directory, is that what you want?

Comment: Not quite. I want to open the expanded file right away...

Comment: tab-completion doesn't work like that anyway, you must complete first then hit enter which is what that snippet does for the example you provided.

Comment: Ok, right. However, it's rather an alias for opening **all** `.tex` in the directory.

Comment: Followed by `<tab>` it does completion, followed by `<Enter>` it opens all the matched files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
complete -f -X '!*.tex' g
```

Then, you can type:

```
g <TAB>
```

And get the completions.  Note: this doesn't complete directories.  Someone else may have a better solution using `compgen`.

There's a helpful autocomplete guide on [The Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html) too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I will have a look into the doc.

Comment: @Jan It works for me. Perhaps you need to add space after g before tab? `g[SPACE][TAB]`. Also you don't need to add `*.tex`.

Comment: Yeah, it should... Maybe it's a different problem. Since even the simple example given [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bash-complete-command) does not work. I will try it on my home computer.

Comment: @Jan Could it be related to the version of bash? Or perhaps there are some bash options set in rc files.

Comment: I have: `bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)` and nothing spectacular in my *.bashrc*

Comment: I will try at home and then go ask our sysadmin... Thanks for the answer. I am sure it is right.

Comment: Too bad. This is what I get with the command and hitting TAB : `~/work/latex/pdaeoptaff$ complete -X -f '!.tex' vim 
Display all 2853 possibilities? (y or n)` ... Sorry for the bad formatting. There is a space after vim and then I hit TAB.

Comment: If what you pasted is a cut and paste, then you forgot the asterisk in `*.tex`.  Also, the order is important--`'!*.tex'` is the argument to the `-X` option.

Comment: Now that I have understood how `complete` works, everything is fine. Thanks!